# GPO - Default File Association from user/machine combination

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, file-association

I have a GPO that uses `ComputerConfiguration\Policies\AdminstrativeTemplates\WindowsComponents\FileExplorer\Set a default associations configuration file` to set the file associations for a particular computer.

Is it possible to control this by a combination of user and computer, rather than just by computer. eg if `UserA` logs onto `Computer1`, they get one set of file associations, but if `UserB` logs onto `Computer1`, they get a different set? I realise I would need multiple GPOs for this setup.

I've tried creating a security group with the users I want to target, but the policy isn't being applied because `Filtering:  Denied (Security)`. I guess this is because it's a computer level policy, and not a user level one? Thanks.

***UPDATE***

In response to @OOOO's comment, there are some settings, such as file associations, that are implemented via a computer policy, but that are also relevant to a particular user.

Imagine the situation that I have two different PDF readers installed on the same machine. A certain group of users expect to use Sumatra PDF because it is more secure (no javascript processing), whereas another group need Acrobat Reader DC because it can handle encrypted attachments. In this situation it makes perfect sense to be able to implement a GPO based on which computer a user is logged in to, or rather, which user is logged into a particular computer.

***UPDATE 2***

I have managed to make this work (I think!), by creating a security group, and adding both the users and the computer into that group. The GPO is applied, and seems to work for the users I have specified, but I am wondering if the computer policy part is working because the computer is in the security group, ***rather than the combination of computer and user***.

Does anyone know if the computer policy is applied because the user and computer are part of the group, or is it just because of the computer's membership in said group?

***1 hour left on the bounty. Does anyone want 50 points for answering the question below?!***

***Does anyone know if the computer policy is applied because the user and computer are part of the group, or is it just because of the computer's membership in said group?***

Comment: Yes, the computer configurations will only be applied to computers, and the user configurations will be only applied to the users. If the policies only be in the computer configurations and if you add the users in the security filter, it will make no sense.